# In the context of food, what is the difference between "raw" and "fresh"? could fresh bacon be called raw bacon?

Tags: word-usage

In the context of food,

> Fresh is any food that is new. The opposite is "stale" or "spoiled" or "bad".
>
> "Raw" is the opposite of "cooked". It can be good to eat (raw carrot) or bad (raw pork).

wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon#Curing_and_smoking) says

> Fresh bacon may then be dried for weeks or months in cold air

obviously, "Fresh bacon" is not cooked, even not dried.

## question

could fresh bacon be called raw bacon?

Comment: Bacon is typically *cured* and so it is not idiomatic to call it “raw”. Raw meat is (in idiom at least) red and bloody - nothing like *uncooked* bacon.

Comment: It is cured so that it will keep. It remains edible even when it isn't freshly butchered.